# Looking for a web based vector graphics editor

Tags: editor, vector-graphics

Here are my criterias:

I'd prefer something with a configurable, polished and preferaby embeddable user interface.  Black and white editing (black lines on white canvas) is fine for my purposes.  Cross-browser compatibility would be nice.  I would rather not use Flash.  Text editing is a must (changing font type and size).

I'm not looking for the perfect editor for my purposes because that surely doesn't exist but something close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Aviary?

http://aviary.com/tools/raven

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it.  It says "Error #2048" upon startup and despite I can see the user interface, I can't draw a damn thing.

Comment: Sorry for accepting your answer so late - In 2010 I'm fairly sure that Aviary was the best application for the task.  Now http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/ is.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple (some broken features) custom-made SVG editor. Looks cool though and you used SVG HTML coding.

https://codehs.com/editor/html/3774203/1907290/svg-editor.html